# Excel - creating a master template?

Tags: microsoft-excel, templates, spreadsheet, master

Sorry for my second Excel question in as many days! Almost there now though :)

I've created a template for an invoice for my mum... is there anyway I can sort of lock the file, and create sub invoices from it, hopefully achieving...

1. Any changes made to the default/master invoice will reflect on all of the others
2. Locking down the spreadsheet so she can only edit certain columns? :D

Any suggestions would be fantastic, thanks

Comment: Since Stack Overflow is a programming website, I'm afraid this question is off-topic. (But for the record, you can't do no. 1 and you can do no. 2 -- check Excel's help for more information).

Comment: ...though you can do no. 1 to some extent at least (again, please refer to the online help).

Answer (score 1):

You can "save as" template.
When Mum double-clicks the doc, that will create a fresh unsaved doc. which is a copy of the template.
In xl, all cells are by default "locked", but you won't see it until you protect the sheet.
So, first, unprotect the input cells (that's in the Format, cells), then lock the sheet (that's in format, sheet).